Removing special character in Mule 4
I'm passing oayload as "item" : "Indoor" and the trying to get the output as "scenario" : "Indoor" but instead in the in the output I below output:
"scenario": "\"Indoor\""

Please help me this I stuck here for whole one to the desired output.

Can you share the code you have written and not just input and output.

Simple code : and scenario is coming from queryParams
"GameType": "cricket" ++ "scenario": ""Indoor""

Actual Output I want is:
{
"GameType": "cricket",
"scenario": "Indoor"
}

is your payload looks like - {
"GameType": "cricket",
"item" : "Indoor"
}
? and desire output is-  { "GameType": "cricket", "scenario": "Indoor" }    please confirm

Edit your question to add that information. Reading code and samples in comments is confusing. Also explain why you don't remove the extra quotes from code. Is not clear what you are doing or how are you using queryParams.

It is very unclear what are you doing. The question is confusing. Please read How to Ask to understand how to improve your question and edit your question to include a minimal reproducible example.

My Input is =  "GameType": "cricket".
I'm sending queryParam = "scenario": "Indoor"
I want output as  = "GameType": "cricket", "scenario": "Indoor"
but instead i'm getting : "GameType": "cricket", "scenario": ""Indoor""

As I said before edit your question to add details.

Input in queryParams
{
   "GameType" : "cricket",
   "scenario" : "Indoor"
}

You can try the following DW to remove double quotes (") inside strings.
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
   "GameType" : attributes.queryParams.GameType,
   "scenario" : read(attributes.queryParams.scenario,"application/json")
}

or
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
   "GameType" : attributes.queryParams.GameType,
   "scenario" : attributes.queryParams.scenario replace '"' with ""
}

Output
{
   "GameType" : "cricket",
   "scenario" : "Indoor"
}


What input did you use? OP wasn't really clear about the input.

@aled Reading the comments, I understood that OP was passing queryParam = "scenario": "Indoor" and he is getting response as "scenario": "\"Indoor\"" so my answer will handle the double quotes within the strings

Add the input to the question so it is clearer.
